# efficiency of different whole-number-mass-to-a-power in balancing a regular triangle/tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, triangles, polyhedra

I saw this qustion:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/186/whats-the-fewest-weights-you-need-to-balance-any-weight-from-1-to-40-pounds

> Suppose you want to create a set of weights so
>   that any object with an integer weight from 1 to 40 pounds can be
>   balanced on a two-sided scale by placing a certain combination of
>   these weights onto that scale.
>
> What is the fewest number of weights you need, and what are their
>   weights?

now the answer was weights of mass in powers of 3 (1,3,9,27, etc.), since they can be placed in either pan like... *apparently this is not really what I conceive of as base-3, but something to the effect of a "-1,0,1" and not 0,1,2...*

anyway, **my question**: what kind of efficient multiples of weight suspended from vertices would be required to balance a regular triangle... and then what kinds of multiples of weights would be required to balance a regular tetrahedron? I am assuming be began as with the scale problem with 1 (or maybe 2 or even 3 in the case of a tetrahedra) of the masses unknown and masses can be placed on any of the vertices to balance it out... presumably in the case of a tetrahedral the answer would vary based on how many vertices had unknown masses attached to them (I am guessing 1 or 3 masses is related to the 4 vertices/faces vs 2 is related to the 6 edges and may have an octahedral type symmetry).

can someone refer me to a good resource? barycentric coordinates seems to only apply in affine space while this seems to be a different sort of problem.

my guess would be that for a triangle the answer is  5^n: 1, 5, 25, 125, etc... no guess for the tetrahedral case except that maybe if there is only an unknown weight on 1 or 3 of the vertices that maybe it could be 7^n and possibly 13^n for the case of 2 unknown vertices

Comment: What do you mean by "balance a triangle"?

Comment: perhaps assuming masses on the vertices of an equilateral triangle or a regular tetrahedron and the centroid is best, assuming the usual side length of 1 and centroid of sqrt(3)/3 from vertex of triangle and sqrt(6)/4 from vertex tetrahedron... the triangle's centroid balanced on an pin and the tetrahedron on a fixed point in it's centroid